Understanding SKLearn's normalization
Whenever I see someone talking about normalization, they usually talk about scaling a feature based on the feature's range, meaning that for a given feature $x$:
$$x' = \frac{x - x_{min}}{x_{max} - x_{min}}$$
For example, let's say you have prices that range from $10$ to $110$ and a particular observation on your dataset has a price of $60$; after the normalization, it would take the value of $0.5$.
$$\frac{60 - 10}{110 - 10} = 0.5$$
But if we go to SKLearn's documentation, what you see is that their normalization is to scale the observation to have a unit norm, meaning that if we have another feature with value 10 on that observation, we will not look for the values of the price feature, but rather to the values of the observation, and normalize $60$ to have the value of $0.98$:
$$
\frac{60}{\sqrt{60^2 + 10^2}} = 0.986
$$
My questions are:

Why is it done like that?
Why are those two different operations treated with the same name?
In which context would you use one or the other?

